# Need to extend batch functionality to checkout multiple files from SVN

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, svn

I have a batch script that checks out any project from the SVN when typed. I have to extend the functionality so that multiple files that user decides can be checked out and a simple approach to it. Right now, my script lists the files from SVN, gives user the choice of entering any name and checks out the trunk of every project using a very basic navigation method. The code is provided below :

echo ============================================================
echo This batch file will automate checking out a project from eclipse 
echo ============================================================  %NL%

```
set svnroot= svn://some_dir
set svnroot_temp= %svnroot%

svn ls !svnroot_temp!
:top
set /p direct=Enter directory..press 1 at anytime to return to root directory and type checkout at anytime to checkout the project :
if /i !direct!==checkout ( cls
set   loc=!svnroot_temp!
set   proj=!dir!
if /i !direct!==1  (cls
set svnroot_temp=%svnroot%
svn ls !svnroot_temp!
goto :top
)
set svnroot_temp= !svnroot_temp!/!direct!
svn ls !svnroot_temp!
set dir=!direct!
goto :top
)



if exist "%javawork%/%proj%/" ( echo  %NL%project already  exists... 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >NUL
echo %NL%updating the folder%NL%  
svn update %javawork%/%proj%/* 
goto :correct
)  
set CheckOutLocation= user_preferred_location

svn checkout %loc%/trunk  %CheckOutLocation%/%proj%/trunk/

echo %NL%%NL% Copying was successful! %NL%

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
```

I wanted help in knowing if there is an easier way so that more projects can be checked out from SVN. Like setting numbers to the svn ls list and then choosing numbers for the projects to checkout. Or any way of making checking out many projects more convenient. Any help will be appreciated . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add numbers to `svn ls` by piping it to `findstr /n` and then input a space-delimited sequence of project numbers to checkout:

```
svn ls !svnroot_temp! | findstr /n .
set /p checkout=Enter space-delimited numbers of projects to checkout

set projNo=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('svn ls !svnroot_temp!') do (
    set /a projNo+=1
    for %%b in (!checkout!) do if %%b==!projNo! (
        svn checkout %%a/trunk %CheckOutLocation%/%%a/trunk/
    )
)
```

Comment: When I try running this , the project name doesn't get checked out because it is taking the number to checkout .  So the code always fails since the project doesn't exist. ( say ../24/trunk/) . Can you help me point out why it is not getting mapped?

Comment: I don't understand what "the project name doesn't get checked out because it is taking the number to checkout" means. My code checks out a name taken from `svn ls`, not a number. Make a screenshot or something.